# Find out the longest word from a sentence - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Is there any way to find out the longest word in Javascript? It should ignore punctuation marks too!

I understood the logic, but the code... *sigh*

Here's what we do -

1. Count the number of alphanumeric characters that are together, not separated by a space or any sign.
2. Get their lengths.
3. Find the biggest length in all.
4. Return the word with the biggest length.

Hope I'm making myself clear...

Comment: Code?? u must tried something.

Comment: @hvgotcodes no, just a challenge I found on [Coderbyte](http://www.coderbyte.com/)

Comment: @Namanyayg haha, it's not supposed to be 'find someone else to do the challenge' ;)

Comment: @RyanMcDonough I came here after I could find no solution to it. I usually search a lot and figure out a solution on my own, but here, I didn't even knew where to start.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Split the string, loop over the parts and keep track of the longest one.

Something like this:

```
var parts = sentence.split();
var longestIndex = -1;
var longestWord = 0;

for(var i=0; i < parts.length; i++){
    if(parts[i].length > longestWord){
        longestWord = parts[i].length;
        longestIndex = i;
    }
}

alert("longest word is " + parts[longestIndex] + ": " + longestWord + " characters");
```

If you need to split on non alphabetic characters as well as spaces you need to use regexes. You can change this line:

```
var parts = sentence.split();
```

To this (thanks Kooilnc for the regex):

```
var parts = sentence.match(/\w[a-z]{0,}/gi);
```

[Working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pQa6N/1/)

Comment: I need the code, I'm pretty sure I understood the logic. I'm such a noob that I don't even know how to split the strings.

Comment: @Namanyayg are you sure of "noob" thing? your personal site says "I Design
Amazing
Websites and themes!" :-)

Comment: _Design_, not _develop_. Big difference.

Comment: JS isn't required to design 'amazing websites and themes' :P
I do client-side JS okay-ish ( I don't use it much, just for editing JQ plugins) and am thinking of brushing up programming JS.

Comment: for (i in parts) is NOT the way to loop over an array

Comment: @hvgotcodes why not, it works fine. It's not a jQuery question. http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for_in.asp

Comment: yeah in that very link, it says for/in loops over **properties in an object** not indexes in the array.  Print out `i` for each iteration in the loop.

Comment: It's untested code, I thought I used it like that before. In any case, I updated the code to use a conventional for loop, that way it should work without question.

Comment: @Namanyayg I updated my answer to split the sentence based on spaces and no alphabetic characters. I provided a working jsfiddle.

Comment: @Jeroen: you could've mentioned the origin of the regular expression, right?

Comment: @Kooilnc sorry, of course :) An upvote for my gratitude/respect

Comment: @Jeroen I didnt say it wouldn't work; I said it wasn't correct. Check this out http://jsfiddle.net/pQa6N/2/.

Comment: I've been using it like that for a while now, cross browser, no problems. Why isn't it correct?

Comment: @hvgotcodes: you are mixing Object looping with Array looping. Therefore it is your code @ jsfiddle.net/pQa6N/2 that is not correct.

Comment: @KooiInc originally he was looping over the array with a for/in.  Your point is my point.  My code is intentionally broken to show the error...

Comment: @hvgotcodes: ok, missed that version, sorry. @Jeroen: don't use `for ... in` on Arrays, it may give unpredictable results. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/javascript-for-in-with-arrays

Answer (score 8):

```
var longest_word = arr.reduce(function (x, y) { return x.length > y.length ? x : y; });
```

There you go.

Using it:

```
var arr = [ 'lol', 'loll', 'lollll', 'lo', 'l' ];
var longest_word = arr.reduce(function (x, y) { return x.length > y.length ? x : y; });
```

So turn your sentence into an array, then the variable longest_word will be the longest word in that array.

Comment: Prettier solution than mine :)

Comment: Could you tell me where to go from here? I need to split a sentence, based on the number of spaces AND non-alphabetical characters, then find out the longest word from them..

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
sentence_array = sentence.split(' ');
var longest = sentence_array.sort(function (a, b) { return b.length - a.length; })[0];
```

Comment: What does the [0] mean at the end?

Comment: Before the `[0]`, the code was sorting the array of words by length. The `[0]` selects the first element (remember, numbering starts from 0, not 1).

Comment: if your sentence has two words with the same length which are longest, using [0] or [1] you can select particular word

Answer (score 2):

You can split a string to an array of words only (no sepators, digits etc) using the `match` method, and sort that descending on length of each element, after which element 0 is the longest word.

It could be a `String.prototype` extension

```
String.prototype.longestWord = function(){
  return (this.match(/\w[a-z]{0,}/gi) || [''])
          .sort(function(a,b){return b.length-a.length;})[0];
}
//usage
'We saw it ...! A lazy cat walking - or did we?'.longestWord(); //=> walking
'------------'.longestWord();                                   //=> ''
'---aa--b----'.longestWord();                                   //=> 'aa'
```

The same as a function, using `Array.reduce`

```
function longestWord(str){
   return (str.match(/\w[a-z]{0,}/gi) || [''])
           .reduce( function(a,b){return a.length>b.length ? a : b;} );
}
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/qcA2n/)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I attempted to solve the problem:

```
function LongestWord(sen) { 
    var wordArray = sen.match(/\w+/gi);
    var longest = 0; 
    var word = undefined; 
  for(var i = 0; i < wordArray.length; i++){
    if(wordArray[i].length > longest){
       word = wordArray[i];
      longest = word.length;
    }
  }

  return word; 

}
```