# On Input change push elements to array to be checked against a different array

Tags: javascript

I have a text box that users can enter information into. I need to, on the fly, check if any words that the user enter equals a word from my pre-set list and if a word the user entered matches a word in my list do X or Y.

I can do the checking no problem but I am stuck on how I can push full words from my input field using the onchange or another function.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Show us what you've got so far, sir!

Comment: So your question is: _how to split a string into words_? You should be able to search for lots of answers to that question. For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31105452/splitting-sentence-into-array-of-words

Comment: I made this jsfiddle based on what I think what you're asking.. See if this is what you were after.. https://jsfiddle.net/ekfnbexb/7/

Comment: @MattBurland Yes and no. The main portion of my question is how can I "do" the check of the two arrays against each other on the fly. IE: as the person is typing as soon as they enter "yes" X happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think maybe this is what you were looking to do. Am I right?

```js
var array = [];
var words = ["test","okay","cool"];

$("#words").on("change",function(){

var str = $("#words").val() 
var splitwords = str.split(" ");

if(splitwords.some(r=> words.includes(r))== true)
{
alert("word exists");
//do some stuff
}
else
{
alert("word doesn't exist")
}

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

enter a string <input type = "text" id = "words">
```

Comment: Yes this is close. But I need the user to be able to enter more than one word. If I type in just "test" right now it will trigger, but if I type in "I am a test" it does not.

Comment: Okay. I've fixed it. Instead of onkeyup, it is onchange now. But you could make it onkeyup with some tweaking if you needed to.

Comment: That is perfect. I wound up figuring it out and doing it another way but you post helped me a ton. This is how I did it https://gist.github.com/rameden/01224c3c1539108d0c8925e825030ffc

Comment: How would you go about detecting phrases? IE: If the person typed "help me"

Comment: for that.. You could use regular expressions. Check out this site to help you build the expressions for the phrases you're looking for. Here's one I made for 'help me' https://regexr.com/3n800

Comment: here. Check out this jsfiddle. It does what you're asking. https://jsfiddle.net/ekfnbexb/76/